# Arcgis create random points using minumum allowed distance

Tags: random, arcgis

I am working in Arcgis 10.3.1 and I am trying to add some random points into a polygon shapefile as the center for circular sampling plots, however, every time I use the minimum allowed distance (I use 15 m because the plot radius will be 10 m) I get an error. 
Without using the minimum allowed distance it works fine but usually the samples spacing is not right.
I was thinking maybe there was not space in the area to have such spacing but the area i 4000 m2 and a 10m radius circular plot is only around 300m2 (I need only 4). Even if I use 2m distance I get the error.
I am not sure if I am using it right. Is there any other way to add random points?

Any imput is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just figure out what was happening. 
Apparently there was a file with the same name as my output and that is why I got the error codes.